# How to make a specific row bold using Kable in r-markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

How to make the third row bold using Kable in rmarkdown? Following is my code for the table.

```
    library(kableExtra)
    table301 <- read.csv("edt.csv")
    
    x <- knitr::kable(table301,"pipe",  
    caption = "Education and Access", 
    position = "center", full_width = F) 
    kableExtra::row_spec(x, 5, bold = TRUE)
```

I am using the following data frame.

| Name | No.of Schools | Composite_Score | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 18 | 52 | 58% |
| B | 8 | 29 | 72% |
| C | 27 | 116 | 86% |
| E | 17 | 50 | 59% |
| F | 6 | 25 | 83% |
| D | 14 | 43 | 61% |

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use  `row_spec(3,bold=T,hline_after = T)`

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

kable(df)%>%
  kable_styling()%>%
  row_spec(3,bold=T,hline_after = T)
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "D"), No.of_Schools = c(18L, 
8L, 27L, 17L, 6L, 14L), Composite_Score = c(52L, 29L, 116L, 50L, 
25L, 43L), Percentage = c("58%", "72%", "86%", "59%", "83%", 
"61%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```